# Apps script: Invalid assignment left-hand side

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

in apps script I have:

```
var conversations = [R: test1 ,  R: test3 ,  tx ,  I sent ]
```

I wanted to get a list of elements containing 'R:' so I tried

```
var out = conversations.reduce(function (ar, m) {
  m.indexOf('R:')!== -1 && ar.push(m);
  return ar;
}, []);
```

Which works and produces:

```
 [R: test1 ,  R: test3 ]
```

Next I tried to get the last element of array containing 'R:' which would be

```
R: test3
```

I changed the code to:

```
var out = conversations.reduce(function (ar, m) {
m.indexOf('R:')!== -1 && ar=m;
return ar;
 }, "");

Logger.log(out);
```

But now I can't save the function and I'm getting the error in the title. Is it possible to save just the last element in an accumulator? should I ?

Answer (score 2):

You can change you code like below.

```js
var conversations = ['R: test1' ,  'R: test3' ,  'tx' ,  'I sent' ]
var out = conversations.reduce(function (ar, m) {
if(m.indexOf('R:')!== -1){
  ar = m
}
return ar;
 }, "");

console.log(out)
```

But i will use filter in such case and take the last element from filtered value

```js
var conversations = ['R: test1' ,  'R: test3' ,  'tx' ,  'I sent' ]
var out = conversations.filter(function(m){
  return m.indexOf('R:')!== -1
}).splice(-1)

console.log(out)
```

Comment: @Rubén sorry didn't knew that but this can be easily changed to normal function. see the update

Answer (score 1):

`.reduce` is the wrong tool here, use `.find`:

```
const out = conversations.slice().reverse().find(it => it.includes("R:")) || "";
```

Or you could implement your own `findLast`:

```
function findLast(array, predicate) {
  for(let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if(predicate(array[i], i, array)) return array[i];
}

//...
const out = findLast(conversations, it => it.includes("R:"));
```

---

If you just want to remove the error, add brackets to distinguish the assigment from the rest:

```
m.indexOf('R:')!== -1 && (ar=m);
```

But that's ugly, seriously.

Comment: This will not give the last one. Op wants the last one.

Comment: @codeManiac it's a shame that there isn't a `.findLast`

Comment: Google Apps Script hasn't built-in support for arrow functions.

Comment: @JonasWilms yeah i agree similar to reduceRight it's good to have `findRight` or some sort of function.

Comment: @TheMaster simple reason is it's hard to maintain code when it's not readable. imo using `(ar = m )` is not readable. i will go with using if condition

Comment: @theMaster `ar` and `m` are bad variable names, `indexOf() !== -1` is also not quite readable IMO, using `.reduce` here is missleading, just to name a few...

Comment: Apps Script is basically JS 1.6. No includes, no let, no iterators, no arrow syntax. It does have map, filter, reduce, some, and every support.

Comment: @JonasWilms Please star this feature request [Add support for ES6 features](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764074)